# Establishing audio connection after hfp level connection is established

Tags: audio, hfp

I am unable to make audio connection after hfp level connection

I was able to establish hfp level connection. And I am able to use AT commands for call controls. Now for the next step I want to access audio from my pc when mobile connected via bluetooth hfp. To elaborate, I want to use my pc mic and speaker for call audio next and I am facing issue with it. Any solution related to audio connection establishment?